# Renaming Columns in Pandas import csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a header in my dataset that has both " " and ' '. therefore when I use `pd.rename(columns=)` it does not recognize the headder because it has both quotations. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPsmB.png)

I need any other solution other than `pd.rename(columns=)` because it won't work.

Comment: Can you just escape the extra quotes? `print("\"hello\"")` prints `"hello"`.

Comment: It's best to provide your code and resulting output as text, [not as an image/screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5905029).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a potential solution:

```py
import pandas as pd

# == Define Dummy Example ======================================================
qf = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        """89243690: Some column with "double quotes" in the name and 'single quotes'""": [10, 20]
    }
)
```

### Renaming using triple quotes `"""Some text"""`

```py
# Using triple quotes ("""foo bar"""):
qf.rename(
    columns={"""89243690: Some column with "double quotes" in the name and 'single quotes'""": 'New name'}
)
```

**Output:**

|  | New name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 |
| 1 | 20 |

### Matching portion of the column name

```py
# Using portion of the column name, that is unique for the column you want to rename:
partial_column_name = "89243690"
qf.rename(columns={qf.columns[qf.columns.str.contains(partial_column_name)][0]: 'New name'})
```

**Output:**

|  | New name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 |
| 1 | 20 |